# Is pandas performances for batch operations equivalent to SQL?

Tags: sql, pandas

I am using a `Pandas` `DataFrame` in order to search in a big table, based on some condition, like `df['start_date' > datetime.now()]`, etc'. The DataFrame is not sorted or indexed.

Does `pandas` provide similar performances for batch operations, like `SQL` when you use a `WHERE` clause?

Comment: You can use categorical data is you have a huge df : https://www.ritchieng.com/pandas-making-dataframe-smaller-faster/

Comment: I ask about a regular dataframe

Answer (score 0):

If you're really interested in speed comparison between SQL and Pandas, [there's a good article here on it](https://blog.thedataincubator.com/2018/05/sqlite-vs-pandas-performance-benchmarks/#:%7E:text=sqlite%20or%20memory%2Dsqlite%20is%20faster%20for%20the%20following%20tasks%3A&text=1%20millisecond%20for%20any%20data,10x%2D50x%20faster%20with%20sqlite%20.). The TLDR is: they're comparible, SQL is faster for most things (including filtering) but Pandas is faster on a few others.

Performance with both will be affected by the executing machine. Putting a bunch of RAM on a SQL server will speed it up, and a laptop with a large graphics card will handle Panda functions that use vectorisation a lot faster.

It's worth thinking about what an acceptable criteria is in terms of speed performance. Python has some modules like Dask that are specifically designed for handling big data quickly, so might be worth a look if Pandas is performing too slowly for your needs.